# Could not understand implementation of clear method  of HashMap in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I saw java hash map ,the clear method,like this:

```
public void clear() {
    modCount++;
    Entry[] tab = table;
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
        tab[i] = null;
    size = 0;
}
```

I don't understand,why to take new tab to clear.

Why not use table to clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand, why new tab to clear.

It is not a new table ... it is just a local variable.

I can think of three possible reasons:

- Readability, as suggested by @Bhesh Gurung ... though it hardly makes a difference here (IMO).
- It might mitigate (somewhat) the damage caused if one thread calls `clear()` while a second thread does an update that might cause the table to be expanded.  But it certainly doesn't fix the problem, so I'd be inclined to dismiss this as being nonsensical.
- It might improve performance; e.g. since the optimizer knows that the reference in the local variable `tab` cannot change, it can optimize the array bounds checks better.

Of these, I think that the 3rd reason is the most plausible.

(I don't think it is anything to do with the `transient` modifier.  In this case, the modifier is only there for readability.  The `HashMap` class provides `readObject` and `writeObject` which renders the `transient` modifier moot.)

Answer (score 2):

It may be because the `table` field is declared as `transient`, so that it's not part of the persistent state of the HashMap object. The `table` field gets replaced in methods like `resize()`, which isn't synchronized, so it's possible to have the `table` field swapped from underneath you when iterating through all of its entries inside of a `clear()` method call. If it makes a reference to `table` first, and iterates through that reference, we're guaranteed that if the `table` field changes, we're still iterating through the original `table`.

Comment: But then again a `HashMap` is not thread-safe in "normal" operations, so why would it care about it in `clear()`?

Comment: @JoachimSauer If you add more entries in one thread, it calls `resize()`, right after another thread calls `clear()`. Doing this ensures that the `clear()` call sets all of the old entries to null, while the new `table` is being created. Otherwise, at worst case, I could end up with a HashMap of all nulls except for the entry I just added.

Comment: I understand what good thread safety would be. But what I'm saying: `put` alone is not thread-safe (nasty things can happen if multiple threads call it). Then why would they care if one other method is thread-safe?

Comment: @JoachimSauer it isn't thread safe, I assume it was just a precaution to make a call to `clear()` or a `resize()` more predictable.

Comment: How is what you're writing not about thread safety? Nothing can "swap the `table`field underneath you" **unless** there is a second thread involved, at which point the issue is about thread safety.

Comment: @JoachimSauer This involves thread safety, but I'm not claiming it's thread safe, just that it would yield a more predictable result if 2 threads were to, unsafely, cause `clear()` and `resize()` to be called at the same time. I don't know why that would happen, it was just a guess.